# How to compare last some letter of method name in two different class using reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, methods

I have two class

```
class A {
    public String getAb001() {
        return ab001;
    }
    // Other Methods
}

class B {
    public String getXy001() {
        return xy001;
    }
    // Other Methods
}
```

Note: Method consideration: both class's method name differentiate by first two letter of method name (e.g. Ab001 and Xy001, here first two letter is different including get).
I need print success message when Class A methods name is equals to class B method. Here after deducting get+first two letter of method name, it should print success message.
It will help my big problem. Please fill free to share. Thanks in advance

Comment: this is rather odd, it might be an idea to think about a refactoring

Comment: Perhaps is "xy001" and "ab001" ?

Comment: Or, if it is xy001 (a variable) you can use reflection, but this is really a bad way to do oop

Comment: The first three letters of both methods are `get` How do you know how many characters to ignore? Would `getAbc001` or `reset001` also be a match?

Comment: I have to ignore only first 5 letter (e.g get+other two letter). like getMaCity() and getWoCity()

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a simple endeavor, please comment if I'm missing something:

```
boolean areMatch(Method a, Method b) {
  return salientNamePart(a).equals(salientNamePart(b));
}

String salientNamePart(Method m) {
  return m.getName().substring(5);
}
```